# android SupportMapFragment Error inflating fragment class

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity

Happy New Year All,

New with implementing Fragments in Android (and I have seen similar posts but I have not been able to get an answer for my problem), so here goes:

I wish to use SupportMapFragment (referenced from the support library v4) and I have created a class that extends FragmentActivity, called TripSummary.java:

```
package com.project.locationapp;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TripSummary extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    stopService(intent);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trip_summary);

    createMap();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_trip_summary, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Content?
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void createMap(){
    //if a map has not already been instantiated it'll return null
    if(mMap == null){
        //instantiate map
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        //check it has been instantiated
        if(mMap != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "map done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
            //Manipulate map here (add coordinates/polylines from trip etc etc.)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Which gets a layout from activity_trip_summary.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tripSummary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/trip_summary"
    tools:context=".Start" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tripDetails"
    android:layout_below="@id/tripSummary"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/awaiting_location"
    tools:context=".Start" />

<Fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@id/tripDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.project.locationapp"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<permission
      android:name="com.project.locationapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.project.locationapp..permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.project.locationapp.Start"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.project.locationapp.LocationService" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.project.locationapp.TripSummary"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_trip_summary" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.project.locationapp.Start" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.project.locationapp.ViewTrips"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_trips" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.project.locationapp.TripDetail"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_trip_detail" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="<-- My Key -->"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The problem I am having in that each time I try to load the activity TripSummary, I get a 'Sorry! stopped unexpectedly' dialog and the app crashes.

LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity                   ComponentInfo{com.project.locationapp/com.project.locationapp.TripSummary}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class Fragment
```

I am referencing the google-play-services_lib library (which is also in my workspace) and I also have a copy of android-support-v4.jar in /libs directory within my project.

If you know an answer to my problem, please share!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace:

```
<Fragment
```

with:

```
<fragment
```

Also, you can get rid of the redundant/incorrect namespace declarations in that element.

Also also, in the future, post *the complete stack trace*, not just part of one line, to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Thank you. (rookie or what?)

Comment: @user1610177: You're not the first person to get tripped up by the case-sensitivity of `<fragment>`. Generally speaking, most element names in Android are case sensitive. I also just filed a feature request to have the tools warn developers who try `<Fragment>`: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42173

Comment: @CommonsWare google maps API looks like totally crazy. I am getting the "error inflating layout" problem since last 30 days. Please help me. Tried all the fixes available here. Could ask a separate question if u want.